# AnimateDiff ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'einops'

Tags: einops

I was trying to setup AnimateDiff by following instructions here: https://github.com/guoyww/AnimateDiff/blob/main/__assets__/docs/animatediff.md
But the problem is when I run the command "python -m scripts.animate --config configs/prompts/1-ToonYou.yaml" as it shown in the repository, I got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'einops' error.

Actually at first it seems like just a not installed library error. But I have already installed the latest version(0.7.0). I deleted and reinstalled the library. I tried for another versions. I'm not sure if the problem is about the conda environment. But in the environment.yaml file there is listed the requirements. And I manually installed the other required libraries to the same directory. And all libraries worked but einops.